# d3 circles not responding when x axis changed

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a chart that displays circles which represent different events over a timeline. I've included buttons so users can select a timeline view of 3, 6, 12 and 18 months from today. The 12 and 18 month buttons work fine but the 3 and 6 months buttons both fail.

Here's the working code in [blockbuilder](http://blockbuilder.org/brett-j/927ead426ef1450e42e8d3a2e96aef1e).

When I console.log the start and end dates it looks fine. All of the timeline buttons (3, 6, 12 and 18) all return correct dates and times.

I'm completely confused why some buttons work and some don't.

Any ideas why I can specify some days to the timeline but not others?

Comment: why add more complexity to your program when you haven't found the cause/solution of your previous question (the same: month 3 and 6 buttons do not work), adding complexity does not make it easier to find the cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason those "Next *[x]*-months" buttons are not working lies in this piece of your code (line 551 in the current block builder link):

```
else{
    circles.data(d3.voronoi()
    .extent([[-margin.left, -margin.top], [width + margin.right, height + margin.top]])
    .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
    .polygons(MyData))
```

If you examine your data after this, you will find that a lot of your data points have been replaced with `undefined`s. I am not sure what the underlying reason for this is as I have no experience with `d3-voronoi` and in any case, [it has been deprecated and replaced with d3-delaunay](https://github.com/d3/d3-delaunay).

If you do something like:

```
let vdata = d3.voronoi()
    .extent([[-margin.left, -margin.top], [width + margin.right, height + margin.top]])
    .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
    .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
    .polygons(MyData);

    let fdata =[];
    vdata.forEach(d => {if(d) fdata.push(d);});
    circles.data(fdata);
```

You will no longer see the error and buttons will work although I am not sure if the resulting visualization is actually what you want. But the question was about those error-throwing buttons and I believe this is the reason. Hope this helps.

Comment: points at double location in the plane are removed by voronoi but the array is maintained for size and these entries get `null`ed

Comment: @rioV8, The OP can also change their `transition` function to handle the `undefined`s instead of dropping them from the array

Comment: `circles.data(vdata.filter( d => d ))`